# Oracle Label Security and Oracle Database Vault together

Tags: oracle

Today I have a problem with Oracle.
I have Oracle Label Security (OLS) and Oracle Database Vault installed, but OLS is registered, ODV is not.

Today I register ODV too, and now, I can login to Enterprise Manager with user LBACSYS (of OLS) but when I click to OLS on Security tab, EM show me error :

```
You have been logged in to a Database with Database Vault installed on it. You do not have sufficient privileges to access the Database Vault features on Enterprise Manager. Please contact your administrator
```

I don't know how to use OLS with ODV enabled, can you tell me ?

Thanks.

Comment: you could try logging in as the DV owner?